# How to implement a Expander (Accordion of single item) in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I have a **Flex** application that behaves as described below

[image: How to improve this to an Accordion or similar Flex component]

I want to fix two things

1. I want to make clear to the user that more info can be shown. Current "Profundidad" is only a label.
2. The element that is being shown below is not aligned to the one above it, since this is actually another component that is being shown when the state changes

I have tried using Accordion, but when you have a Accordion with a single element, that element is always visible so it can not be collapsed and expanded

What i want is the final result to look as close as posible to this

[image]

Comment: Why do you use an **accordion** for do this? Maybe you can use this componente, check this **[link](http://hasseg.org/stuff/CollapsiblePanel/CollapsiblePanelDemo.swf)**. Here another **[link](http://blog.9mmedia.com/?p=535).**

Comment: @GastonF. I was mentioning a Accordion because I am new to Flex and have not find any out of the box component that behaves as expected

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this using states. First define two states: 'normal' and 'expanded'

```
<s:states>
    <s:State name="normal"/>
    <s:State name="expanded"/>
</s:states>
```

Then use `includeIn` or `excludeFrom` to display components as needed:

```
<!-- always visible components -->
<s:Label text="FPBAF20F"/>
<s:Label text="N/A"/>

<s:Button label="Profundidad" 
          click="currentState = currentState == 'expanded' ? 'normal' : 'expanded'"/>

<!-- the compra/venta grid only shown in 'expanded' state -->
<s:DataGrid includeIn="expanded" />
```

The click handler isn't very pretty, but you get the idea: when you click the Button, the state is toggled from 'normal' to 'expanded' and back when you click again.
That's really all there is to it.

If you prefer an out-of-the-box solution, you're free to use the CollapsiblePanel component I created: https://github.com/RIAstar/CollapsiblePanelFx ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code will be useful:

**MXML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" xmlns:classes="com.classes.*">

    <classes:CollapsiblePanel id="cp" title="Profundidad (Click me)" open="false">
        <mx:DataGrid> 
            <mx:ArrayList>
                <fx:Object Cantidad="" Precio=""/>
            </mx:ArrayList>
        </mx:DataGrid>
    </classes:CollapsiblePanel>
</s:Application>
```

**CollapsiblePanel.as**. Note that in my case, this class is in `com.classes` package, you can put this in the place as you want.

```
package com.classes {
import flash.events.*;
import mx.effects.AnimateProperty;
import mx.events.*;
import mx.containers.Panel;
import mx.core.ScrollPolicy;

[Style(name="closedIcon", property="closedIcon", type="Object")]
[Style(name="openIcon", property="openIcon", type="Object")]

public class CollapsiblePanel extends Panel {
        private var _creationComplete:Boolean = false;
        private var _open:Boolean = true;
        private var _openAnim:AnimateProperty;

        public function CollapsiblePanel(aOpen:Boolean = true):void
        {
            super();
            open = aOpen;
            this.addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, creationCompleteHandler);
        }

        private function creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            this.horizontalScrollPolicy = ScrollPolicy.OFF;
            this.verticalScrollPolicy = ScrollPolicy.OFF;

            _openAnim = new AnimateProperty(this);
            _openAnim.duration = 300;
            _openAnim.property = "height";

            titleBar.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, headerClickHandler);

            _creationComplete = true;
        }

        private function headerClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void { toggleOpen(); }

        private function callUpdateOpenOnCreationComplete(event:FlexEvent):void { updateOpen(); }

        private function updateOpen():void
        {
            if (!_open) height = closedHeight;
            else height = openHeight;
            setTitleIcon();
        }

        private function get openHeight():Number {
            return measuredHeight;
        }

        private function get closedHeight():Number {
            var hh:Number = getStyle("headerHeight");
            if (hh <= 0 || isNaN(hh)) hh = titleBar.height;
            return hh;
        }

        private function setTitleIcon():void
        {
            if (!_open) this.titleIcon = getStyle("closedIcon");
            else this.titleIcon = getStyle("openIcon");
        }

        public function toggleOpen():void
        {
            if (_creationComplete && !_openAnim.isPlaying) {

                _openAnim.fromValue = _openAnim.target.height;
                if (!_open) {
                    _openAnim.toValue = openHeight;
                    _open = true;
                    dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.OPEN));
                }else{
                    _openAnim.toValue = _openAnim.target.closedHeight;
                    _open = false;
                    dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.CLOSE));
                }
                setTitleIcon();
                _openAnim.play();
            }
        }

        public function get open():Boolean {
            return _open;
        }

        public function set open(aValue:Boolean):void {
            _open = aValue;
            if (_creationComplete) updateOpen();
            else this.addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, callUpdateOpenOnCreationComplete, false, 0, true);
            }

        override public function invalidateSize():void {
            super.invalidateSize();
            if (_creationComplete)
                if (_open && !_openAnim.isPlaying) this.height = openHeight;
            }
    }
}
```

Yon can see this SWF in action **[here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/108036807/ExCollapsiblePanelWithGrid.swf)**.

The source code of this ***collapsible panel*** is **[here](http://hasseg.org/blog/post/113/collapsible-panel-component-for-flex/)**.
I hope this will be help you.

Comment: If the asker is using Flex 4 (as the tags suggest), he likely isn't (or shouldn't be, at least) using `mx` components. I can't recall the `spark` equivalents off the top of my head, but you should definitely be using them if using Flex 4

Comment: @JoshJanusch It is correct that you say, but this is an simple example for the asker to see how this works (and because he is new in flex), in my first comment I suggested to him check this link [LINK1](http://blog.9mmedia.com/?p=535), it is for Flex 4.